# How can I implement a provider that is depended on another provider?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am using the provider package with flutter and dart I have a authentication provider and a stream provider that provides a user model. The stream provider that provides the user model is depended on the authentication provider. How can I get my user id to my stream provider?

**This is my multiprovider**

```
MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(builder: (context) => AuthenticationProvider(),),
        StreamProvider<UserModel>.value(value: userStream(//here we call the async method in the Authentication provider to get the user id),
        ),
      ]
```

**This is the method inside the Authentication Provider returns a authentication model which contains the user id**

```
  Future<UserAuthenticationCertificate> userAuthenticationCertificate() async
  {
    FirebaseUser authenticatedUser = await _authentication.currentUser();
    if(authenticatedUser != null)
      return UserAuthenticationCertificate.fromFirebaseAuthentication(authenticatedUser);
    return null;
  }
```

**This is the authentication certificate**

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';

class UserAuthenticationCertificate
{
  String _userID;

  String get userID{
    return _userID;
  }

  UserAuthenticationCertificate(this._userID);

  UserAuthenticationCertificate._internal(this._userID);

  factory UserAuthenticationCertificate.fromFirebase(FirebaseUser firebaseUser)
  {
    return UserAuthenticationCertificate._internal(
      firebaseUser.uid
    );
  }
}
```

**Edit**

This is what I currently have

```
Provider<AuthenticationProvider>(create: (_) => AuthenticationProvider(),),
Provider<UserProvider>(
  create: (_) => UserProvider(),
),
StreamProvider(create: (context) {
  return Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).userStream(Provider.of<AuthenticationProvider>(context).userAuthenticationCertificate());
}),
```

So now I provide the user provider, in a streamprovider? I want to be providing the userModel as the stream how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `context` parameter passed to `create` of your providers to read other providers:

```dart
Provider(create: (_) => Auth()),
StreamProvider(create: (context) {
  return Provider.of<Auth>(context).something;
});
```

Comment: It says that create is an undefined parameter `The named parameter 'create' isn't defined.
Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name ` in both the provider and stream provider?

Comment: You're using an outdated version of provider

Comment: I was indeed using an older version. Question in your example you use the AuthProvider twice. So where does the user provider come in? I tried adding in the user provider in the stream provider but it lead me back to the same problem where I needed my authentication provider.

Comment: I'm not using `Auth` twice. The second one is obtaining the first one, not creating a separate one